# Openssl verify -CRLFile vs -crl_download?

Tags: openssl, verify

I have a docker (running nginx on localhost) which is hosting a CRL file. Using wget I can download the CRL file. My intermediate certificate interm1.crt is listed as revoked in the CRL file.

If I am running the following command:

`openssl verify -crl_check -crl_check_all -CRLfile file.crl -CAfile ca-bundle interm1.crt`

I am getting:

`interm1.crt: ...`
`error 23 at 0 depth lookup:certificate revoked`

which I am expecting. But if I run:

`openssl verify -crl_check -crl_check_all -crl_download -CAfile ca-bundle interm1.crt`

I am getting:

`Error loading CRL from http://127.0.0.1:8080/file.crl`
`interm1.crt: ...`
`error 3 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get certificate CRL`

Why is the crl_download option working differently from the -CRLfile option where as I am using the same file.crl (and can download this file using wget using the same URL)???

I am using:

`openssl version`
`OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016`

Any ideas are appreciated.

BR, Rene

Answer (score 0):

```
-crl_download
```

This fails (with your mentioned error-message) if your CRLs are over 100k.

Apparently this is hardcoded in: 
[#define OCSP_MAX_RESP_LENGTH    (100 * 1024)](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/0c496700631d89a895617af005a338eb280095db/crypto/ocsp/ocsp_ht.c#L34)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately this condition does not hold true in my case. The CRL file has size 1310 bytes.

Comment: Okay. Do you see the request(&possible error) in your webserver logs, when it tries and fails to load the CRL?

Comment: I retested. Now it works :). I do not really know what I have been doing wrongly. I am a bit new in this area (CRL checks). I changed many things in my setup meanwhile. Hard to say what the actual cause was that this initially did not work for me.